# why does jQuery AJAX post null values to the fields that I don't want to change their values?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to update some of the fields of DB table, but when i fill in an specific input, other DB fields become zero. can you help me please what's the problem here?

```
 '</tr>' +


    '<td class="table-active"> <input   type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number"  name="targetInput1" data-coveragetargetsettinginfoid="' +
    targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ1 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange1(this)" ' + q1Disabled + ' /></td>' +


    '<td class="table-active"> <input  type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number"  name="targetInput2" data-coveragetargetsettinginfoid="' +
    targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ2 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange2(this)"' + q2Disabled + ' /></td>' +


    '<td class="table-active"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number"  name="targetInput3" data-coveragetargetsettinginfoid="' +
    targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ3 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange3(this)"' + q3Disabled + ' /></td>' +


    '<td class="table-active"> <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm  text-center number"  name="targetInput4" data-coveragetargetsettinginfoid="' +
    targetSettingInfo.coverageTargetSettingInfoId + '" value="' + targetSettingInfo.targetCurrentQ4 + '" onchange="targetInputOnChange4(this)"' + q4Disabled + ' /></td>' +



    '</tr>' +
.
.
.
......................................................................
```

I wrote a targetInputOnChange function for every  in the table above, the one below is for the first :

```
function targetInputOnChange1( targetInput1) {



var budgetProduct = {

    CoverageTargetSettingInfoId: $(targetInput1).data("coveragetargetsettinginfoid"),

    TargetCurrentQ1: $(targetInput1).val(),


};


$.ajax({
    datatype: "json",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

    url: '/api/coverageTargetSetting/updateCoverageTargetSettingInfo',
    data: JSON.stringify(budgetProduct),
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        unblockUI(500);
        showErrorAlert('', xhr.responseJSON);
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly cross check the parameters name, it should be same as the key name.

for instance this is your function or web method:

public string AddFunc(int number1, int Number2)

your keys name should be ***number1*** and ***Number2*** in the data attribute of ajax call.

Comment: if this is not the issue, then apply the null condition on the possible values which should not be updated if the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved (thanks to  Lajwat Kumar) the problem by setting other fields null in AJAX, and checking for null values in my Service file:
my service.cs:

```
    public void UpdateCoverageTargetSettingInfo(CoverageTargetSettingInfo 
    TargetSettingInfo)
    {
        var TargetSettingInfoToUpdate =


 CoverageRepository.GetById(TargetSettingInfo.CoverageTargetSettingInfoId 
 );


        TargetSettingInfoToUpdate.CoverageTargetSettingInfoId = 
    TargetSettingInfo.CoverageTargetSettingInfoId;
        if (TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ1 != null)
        {

            TargetSettingInfoToUpdate.TargetCurrentQ1 = 
  TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ1;
        }

        if (TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ2 != null)
        {

                TargetSettingInfoToUpdate.TargetCurrentQ2 = 
  TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ2;
        }

        if (TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ3 != null)
        {

                TargetSettingInfoToUpdate.TargetCurrentQ3 = 
TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ3;
        }

        if (TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ4!=null)
        {
                TargetSettingInfoToUpdate.TargetCurrentQ4 = 
TargetSettingInfo.TargetCurrentQ4;
        }
```

...................................................

using null values for other fields:

```
 function targetInputOnChange1( targetInput1) {

var budgetProduct = {

    CoverageTargetSettingInfoId: 
$(targetInput1).data("coveragetargetsettinginfoid1"),

    TargetCurrentQ1: $(targetInput1).val(),
    TargetCurrentQ3: null,
    TargetCurrentQ2: null,
    TargetCurrentQ4: null

};
```